# bash function with ssh

Tags: ssh, bash, remote

I am just getting into bash for the first time.

How would I run a function on the server in this scope? drush status is something only on the server being ssh connected too.

```
#!/bin/bash

function test {
    drush status
}

function connect {
    ssh user@serveraddress 'test'

}

connect
```

I understand you need to put the remote code in the ssh user@server 'code here', however complicated things get confused with all the '" etc. For instance this should echo all the db names of the server.

```
function connect {


    ssh user@serveraddress 
   '

    dbuser=user
    dbpass=pass
    DBS=`mysql -u$dbuser -p$dbpass -Bse 'show databases'| egrep -v 'information_sch$
    for db in $DBS; do
        echo "DB name -  $db"
    done

    '   
}


connect
```

Any help links appreciated, cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use here-documents:

```
ssh user@serveraddress <<"END"
dbuser=user
dbpass=pass
DBS=$(mysql -u$dbuser -p$dbpass -Bse 'show databases'| egrep -v 'information_sch$')
for db in $DBS; do
    echo "DB name -  $db"
done
END
```

See: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html

Comment: thankyou very much there are afterall a few ways to get this done. I know this will come in handy again. To avoid the `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.` I added a -T to the `ssh -T user@serveraddress`.

Answer (score 2):

Can you not just put your script on the remote host and use ssh to run it

```
ssh user@remote.tld /path/to/script
```

Or if your script requires no command line parameters ypu can do this

```
cat script | ssh user@remote.tld
```

EDIT:

After some more research then this is probably a better solution all round

```
ssh user@remote.tld 'bash -s' <script
```

or

```
ssh user@remote.tld 'bash -s' <script param1 param2
```

> If  the -s option is present, or if no arguments remain after
>                    option processing, then commands are read from  the  standard
>                    input.   This  option  allows the positional parameters to be
>                    set when invoking an interactive shell.

Answer (score 0):

another way...

```
function connect {

    dbuser=user
    dbpass=pass
    DBS=`ssh user@serveraddress "mysql -u$dbuser -p$dbpass -Bse 'show databases'"|egrep -v 'information_sch$'`
    for db in $DBS; do
        echo "DB name -  $db"
    done

}
```

In other words: Only run the most necessary code on the remote machine, the rest local.
Or - don't use backticks at all:

```
function connect {

    dbuser=user
    dbpass=pass
    ssh user@serveraddress "mysql -u$dbuser -p$dbpass -Bse 'show databases'" \
    |egrep -v 'information_sch$' \
    |while read db; do
        echo "DB name -  $db"
    done

}
```